# Custom Web Part property is applied to all web parts when configured

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, custom-properties

I am facing an issue with SharePoint 2010 Web part Properties. I have created a Custom Web Part Property with Boolean type.

Now I am adding this web part to 3 different pages when I set this property of any single web part it is applied to all web parts in all 3 pages.

I want to apply that property to single web part only not all. What should I do?

Below is my Code.

```
    public static Boolean WP_EnableRatingsPages;
    [Category("Extended Settings"),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
    WebBrowsable(true),
    WebDisplayName("Enable Rattings"),
    WebDescription("Enable Rattings")]
    public Boolean _WP_EnableRatingsPages
    {
        get { return WP_EnableRatingsPages; }
        set { WP_EnableRatingsPages = value; }
    }
```

If user has clicked on "Enable Ratings" it will just display rating image in web part.

Comment: Without code it is very hard to tell what is going wrong!

Comment: Hi Robert, please check my question again. I have added my code for property. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made your WebPart property `static`. That is why all instances of the WebPart are sharing the value.

It should be:

```
public Boolean WP_EnableRatingsPages;
[Category("Extended Settings"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Enable Rattings"),
WebDescription("Enable Rattings")]
public Boolean _WP_EnableRatingsPages
{
    get { return WP_EnableRatingsPages; }
    set { WP_EnableRatingsPages = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vardhaman, It solved my problem. I am facing another issue i.e. "Enable Ratings" is resetting everyday. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Does the resetting also occur after you have removed the `static` keyword.

Comment: It it resetting everyday. 
Do you think it is problem of "Static" keyword?